# Mysql PDO, query exec is failing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have encountered odd problem while upgreading one of my applications

- script language is PHP
- database is MYSQL
- i use PDO class to process

i had this simple user update module that contained 4 different fields and was working just fine, today i decided to add ability to update user group and query exec is failing since then.

in db - users table has following fields:

- username (varchar 50)
- password (varchar 64)
- email (varchar 128)
- name (varchar 50)
- group (int 1)
- active (int 1)

query i was performing while update, before the upgreade was this:

```
UPDATE users SET username = ?, email = ?, name = ?, active = ? WHERE id = 1
Array
(
    [username] => john
    [email] => john.doe@gmail.com
    [name] => John Doe
    [active] => 1
)
```

It was working just fine, now query i am performing is this:

```
UPDATE users SET username = ?, email = ?, name = ?, group = ?, active = ? WHERE id = 1
Array
(
    [username] => john
    [email] => john.doe@gmail.com
    [name] => John Doe
    [group] => 2
    [active] => 1
)
```

This one isnt working, however if i did check errorinfo it returns array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [0] => 
    [0] => 
)
```

So i tried to only update group without other fields this way:

```
UPDATE users SET group = ? WHERE id = 1
Array
(
    [group] => 2
)
```

Also failed, which is weird beacuse if i copy it into phpmyadmin sql runer it is being executed properly.

The code that does exec is this:

```
if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
    if(count($params)) {
        $x = 1;
        foreach($params as $param) {
            $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
            $x++;
        }
    }

    if($this->_query->execute()) {
        $this->_insertid = $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
        $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
    } else {
        $this->_error = true;
    }
}
```

Again everything is working unless i try to update group, only then it fails, that i dont understand maybe someone does, appriciate all the tips :)

BTW maybe worth mentioning that when i `INSERT` instead of `UPDATE` it is being exec'd properly, only Update has some issues

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: i dont think that mysqli command will work for PDO class

Comment: Then use: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: i do think that i included report from errorinfo in my topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group is a **reserved word** in MySQL 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Don't know if something else is also wrong in your code but try using ``` `` ``` around the [reserved] words:

```
`group`
```

Comment: *"Group is a banned word"* - Bit of a harsh word. It's not "banned", once can use it, but more of a "reserved keyword".

Comment: what wouldnt it be or called like, guy is brilliant:D it has worked:) it is odd though when i insert or select and say group its working and if i update it needs those markings around... either way thank you for the help mate:)